# How can I check if an Object respect all fields of a GraphQLObjectType?

Tags: graphql-java

I want to know if it's possible to validate a Json receive from another service with a GraphQLObjectType

Example :

I have this Json :

"{\"id\": 1}"

And this type GraphQL

type Document {

```
id: ID!
label: String!
```

}

This Json doesn't respect the Document type because label is required in my type

I am using GraphQL Java

Comment: You know it is your job to research right?

Comment: Yes I know I'm blocked

Comment: The answer to your question is probably either "yes" or "no". I expect that such an answer is not helpful to you. So please read the [help] pages on how to write a good question for this site.

Comment: Ok thank you Adrian

Comment: graphql-java will automatically validate and reject input values, but since you're asking for `GraphQLObjectType` and not `GraphQLInputObjectType`, you're dealing with output values. graphql-java will validate those as well, but I'm not aware of the ability to run the validation ahead of time yourself. I can see the utility to it, though. You may wish to ask this in graphql-java [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/graphql-java/graphql-java?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).